# Regular Expression C# Assert String is Fraction

Tags: c#, .net, regex, fractions

All,

I need 2 regex expression that will work in .NET to detect whether the user typed in a fraction:

1. Only fractional values without any whole parts (don't want to check for 1 1/4, 3 1/2, etc.)
   ONLY: 1/2, 3/4, 8/3, etc. The numerator, denominator can be floating point or integers.
2. ALL valid fractions such as 1/3, 2/3, 1 1/4, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: #1. \d/{1}\d  (I don't know how to do #2)

Comment: Keep in mind, just `\d` only matches a single digit. To match 0 or more, you use `\d*`. To match 1 more more, use `\d+`. In the same logic, you dont need the `{1}` after the `/` because its implied that you meant "a single literal slash"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For the first**

For any fraction in the form of `##/##`, where the numerator or denominator could be of any length, you could just use:

```
\d+(\.\d+)?/\d+(\.\d+)?
```

Grab as many digits as you can immediately before and after a literal slash, as long as there's at least one or more of those digits. If there's a decimal point, it also must be followed by one or more digits, but that whole group is optional and can only appear once.

**For the second**

Assuming it *must* be a fraction, so a whole number alone like `1` would not count, just stick the following on the front

```
\d*\s*
```

Grab some digits and whitespace before the rest of the fraction.

Comment: The question asks for "2 regex expression"; the "`1 1/4` allowed" example was a requirement for the second regular expression; the "`1 1/4` not allowed" example was for the first.

Comment: For #1 (1st regex), no whole parts, for #2 (2nd regex) I need regex that includes whole parts,- ie. I am looking for 2 different regular expressions.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you when you say it must be a fraction (in the second regex)? So the example you gave me for 2nd, which checks only for digits followed by spaces, do I add this to the first expr?

Comment: The full regex for the second would be `\d*\s*\d+(\.\d+)?/\d+(\.\d+)?`. It will allow things like 1/2, 1.2/4, 1/5.67 (because you said they could be floats), and 1 1/2, but it wont allow simply 1, or 10

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
/// <summary>
/// A regular expression to match fractional expression such as '1 2/3'.
/// It's up to the user to validate that the expression makes sense. In this context, the fractional portion
/// must be less than 1 (e.g., '2 3/2' does not make sense), and the denominator must be non-zero.
/// </summary>
static Regex FractionalNumberPattern = new Regex(@"
    ^                     # anchor the start of the match at the beginning of the string, then...
    (?<integer>-?\d+)     # match the integer portion of the expression, an optionally signed integer, then...
    \s+                   # match one or more whitespace characters, then...
    (?<numerator>\d+)     # match the numerator, an unsigned decimal integer
                          #   consisting of one or more decimal digits), then...
    /                     # match the solidus (fraction separator, vinculum) that separates numerator from denominator
    (?<denominator>\d+)   # match the denominator, an unsigned decimal integer
                          #   consisting of one or more decimal digits), then...
    $                     # anchor the end of the match at the end of the string
    ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
    );

/// <summary>
/// A regular expression to match a fraction (rational number) in its usual format.
/// The user is responsible for checking that the fraction makes sense in the context
/// (e.g., 12/0 is perfectly legal, but has an undefined value)
/// </summary>
static Regex RationalNumberPattern = new Regex(@"
    ^                     # anchor the start of the match at the beginning of the string, then...
    (?<numerator>-?\d+)   # match the numerator, an optionally signed decimal integer
                          #   consisting of an optional minus sign, followed by one or more decimal digits), then...
    /                     # match the solidus (fraction separator, vinculum) that separates numerator from denominator
    (?<denominator>-?\d+) # match the denominator, an optionally signed decimal integer
                          #   consisting of an optional minus sign, followed by one or more decimal digits), then...
    $                     # anchor the end of the match at the end of the string
    " , RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace );
```